# Press button to another pages Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, init

How is the coding if I want a page which it changes/switches to another page when I input a value and press the button? I am using python GUI (Tkinter). For example, when I press the button and the input value is lower than 10, the original page will switch to another page with red colour. If the input value is higher than 10, page will be switched to a page with blue color, and so on.

Comment: Have you looked at `tkinter` tutorials? Can you please show us the code you have so far?

Comment: You can use config to change bg to your color

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first page to be destroyed i suggest you do this :

**this is the first screen : **
you should add an input to it to collect the value you want

```
root = Tk()
stp = ttk.Button(root,text='stop',command=root.destroy)
stp.grid(column=1,row=4,ipadx=20,ipady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

in that case stp is a button that destroys the root window and get you out of the mainloop to the rest of the code

after you set up the main screen, when you collect the value, you could create the condition that shows a different window on each case depending on the value you got

```
#add an input and set its result to value
if (value > 10):
    root = Tk()
    #the success screen 
    root.mainloop()
else :
    root = Tk()
    #the other screen
    root.mainloop()
```

so basically the first window will be created after the root window got destroyed if the value is > 10, else the second window will be created

Comment: Given that OP isn't familiar with basic `tkinter` concepts, it would be better if you used `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` for the second window